# remove the compatibility view button from IE 'internet explorer' programatically?

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a website that I would like never to viewed in compatibility mode.

For example, I had to explain to my client why not to view sites with this button selected.

[image]

My question is, how can I stop this button from being activated, or my site from ever being viewed in compatibility mode?

For example [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) - has no compatibility view button on there site!?

How can I do this for all versions of IE which have compatibility mode option?

I tried this...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

But the button is still there?

Any ideas would be great thanks.

---

It is not validating, am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried just using content="IE=edge" without the 9,8,7 entries?

Comment: Yeh just tried `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` and in IE8 - button still works :(

Answer (score 2):

Try just using IE=edge:

```
<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge” />
```

**Add this meta tag as the first thing in `<head>`**. Using just the one should force your users' browser to render in the most recent standards mode.

I've not used multiples in the content attribute, but IE shows the compatibility mode button when it sees that it has options to render in an older version.  Using only one tells it doesn't have any options, and should remove it.

Comment: I'm liking the theory - but `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` not removing button in IE8

Comment: I didn't say it "*must* be the first thing in head", I said to add it as the first thing in head because it's easier and more concise instructions when answering a question.  It does need to be in the head, though, and generally for consistency, the majority of the web puts it near the top of head.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send a HTTP header. In ASP.NET it is like:

```
Response.AddHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm working a wordpress website - ahh maybe my <?php wp_head(); ?> is adding something

Comment: @Joshc That could be it.  Have you viewed source on the page after it's been rendered to see if there's anything there?

Comment: I haven't been coding in PHP for 5 years, but I would write `header("X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge");`. In XHTML you have to close the meta tag `<meta ... />`.